# How to define Enum inside an Enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I need to define data base table and its' columns as enum. My idea was to define an enum call Table and define separate enums with columns in table.

My column interface is as such :

```
public interface Column {

}
```

My data base table enum :

```
public enum Table {


ORDER(orderTableColumn);

private Column column;

public Column getColumn() {
    return column;
}

public void setColumn(Column column) {
    this.column = column;
}

private Table(Column column) {
    this.column = column;
}
```

}

My column enum.

```
public enum OrderTableColumn implements Column {

ORDER_NUMBER("orderId");

private OrderTableColumn(String columnName) {
    this.columnName = columnName;
}

private String columnName;

public String getColumnName() {
    return columnName;
}

public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
    this.columnName = columnName;
}
```

}

But this is not working . Can any one have a solution to this ?

Comment: This is likely invalid syntax:  `ORDER(orderTableColumn);`.  Unless you have an instance of `orderTableColumn` you omitted, I don't see this compiling.  Also, be more specific about "not working" - does it not compile?  Does it not run?  Does it not give the right results?

Comment: This is not compiling , I want to compile it with same architecture. Is there any way to compile it  ?

Comment: By...fixing the syntax issue.  What do you mean by `ORDER(orderTableColumn)`?

Comment: I wanted to pass column enum type in to the constructor of Table enum type.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you want this syntax instead:

```
ORDER(OrderTableColumn.ORDER_NUMBER);
```

The reason this works is that `OrderTableColumn` implements `Column`, which is what `Table` requires to instantiate an enumeration.

Comment: I need to add more than one column is it possible to add it ?

Comment: Sure.  Just create another value in your `OrderTableColumn` enumeration, then add it to the corresponding `Table`.  Although I confess your design is ***very*** strange - it's still possible.

Comment: What I wanted to do is , refer column names any where in the code , and it should be like this, ORDER.ORDER_NUMBER or ORDER.columns.ORDER_NUMBER

Comment: Not possible with your current design.  You should only use the one enumeration, really - have `OrderTableColumn.ORDER_NUMBER` represent the column.  At best, you can get `Table.ORDER.getColumn().getColumnName()` to pull back that information.

Comment: Seems I've to change the design . Thanx for the help